# I want to return a value that is greater than 5, and less then 20 using Comparison operations, but when ran I get an invalid syntax on the '<' sign

Tags: python, comparison

```
import arcpy    
arcpy.env.workspace = "E:/GEOG488_lecture10data"    
from arcpy.sa import*    
arcpy.CheckOutExtension('Spatial')    
sloperaster = arcpy.Raster('slope')    
Modslope = sloperaster > 5 and < 20
```

I am looking for slopes that fall between 5 and 20, but I continue to get an invalid syntax on the less than sign.

Comment: Because that's not valid syntax. Use `sloperaster > 5 and sloperaster < 20` or `5 < sloperaster < 20`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 20 > variable > 5
```

This is a simple solution that checks both that variable is greater than 5 and less than 20

Comment: Incorrect description. Your code checks if the value is greater than 5 and less **or equal** than 20.

Comment: Nope, I checked it myself, my description is correct

Comment: You want to tell me that you used `variable = 20` and that the result was `False`? Never. `>=` is and was alway "greater or equal".

Comment: If `variable` is set to 21 it returns false and if `variable` is set to 4 it returns false as well. Anything in between these two numbers returns true.

Comment: But you wrote "variable is greater than 5 and less than 20" in your answer. "less" means, that a value of `20` would be invalid.

Comment: I meant to set 20 to 19 my bad

Comment: One last question: Did you think about a value of `19.5` which is less than `20` but will be rejected by your code?

Comment: My bad again, I'm an idiot, it should be `20 > variable > 5`